# Sencha Touch google maps get address name

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch-2

I have implemented map in my Sencha Touch application. And I want to get the location name or address. 
Is this possible to get the address of the current location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the address of the location by using the Google Maps API :

```
  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
        latlng   = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
          console.info("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        console.info("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning that using the great answer above, you should add this to your html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

See more details here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

You need to register yourself to Google API first.